# Generating filed name with concat

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has column names `m1,m2,m3...,m12`.
I'm using iterator to select them and insert them one by one in another table.
In this iterator I'm trying to generate filed names with:

```
'['+concat('m',cast(@P_MONTH as nvarchar))+']'
```

where `@P_MONTH` is incrementing in each loop.
so for `@P_MONTH = 1` this suppose to give `[m1]` which works fine.

But when I run query I get:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '[m1]' to data
>   type int.

And if I put simply `[m1]` in that select it works ok.

How to concat filed name so it can be actually interpreted as filed name from certain table?

**EDIT**

Here is full query:

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500),
@P_YEAR int,
@P_MONTH int = 1
set @P_YEAR = 2018
WHILE @P_MONTH < 13
BEGIN
    SET @SQLString = 
    'INSERT INTO [dbo].[MASTER_TABLE]
                (sector,serial,
                date, number, source)'+
    'SELECT ' + '[SECTOR],[DEPARTMENT]' + 
                QUOTENAME(cast(CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@P_YEAR)+RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@P_MONTH),2)+'01',5) as nvarchar))+
                QUOTENAME ('M',cast(@P_MONTH as nvarchar)) +
                'EMPLOYED' +
    'FROM [dbo].[STATS]'+
    'where YEAR= @P_YEAR'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
        SET @P_MONTH = @P_MONTH + 1
END
```

It's still not working. It executes successfully but it does nothing.

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL for that. You first iterate constructing an SQL statement, and then you run it with sp_executesql https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Please provide your declaration, etc. to better understand your problem? Also include your expected results?

Comment: Also, you are mixing `CONCAT` with `+`, which seems a bit odd, you could simply use `CONCAT('[m', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @p_month), ']');`

Comment: @RichardHansell - I've tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: Richard, Much better to use QUOTENAME instead of CONCAT in order to add the brackets to a sysname.

Comment: Harvey, please provide the full query which you use and not only part. Let's see where in the query you use this and how. In general if you use simple `SELECT '['+concat('m',cast(@P_MONTH as nvarchar))+']' FROM T` then the server use this as string and not as column name

Comment: @RonenAriely Yes! This worked: 
    QUOTENAME ('M',cast(@P_MONTH as nvarchar)),

Comment: There is a LOT that can be improved here. The year variable is used as a constant - so why bother with a variable at all? But you cannot debug what you cannot see. Run your loop but select the statement you build rather than execute it. Take that output, copy it into another query window, examine the code and look for problems, run each one separately, evaluate the result, correct as needed. This is just basic debugging - something you should know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day,

Let's create a simple table for the sake of the explanation

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T
GO
CREATE TABLE T(a1 INT)
GO
INSERT T(a1) VALUES (1),(2)
GO
SELECT a1 FROM T
GO
```

When we are using a query like bellow, the server parse the text as a value and not as a column name

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(10)
SELECT @String = '1'
--
SELECT '['+concat('a',cast(@String as nvarchar))+']'
FROM T
GO
```

This mean that the result will be 2 rows with no name for the column and the value will be "[a1]"

Moreover, the above query uses the brackets as part of the string.

One simple solution is to use the function QUOTENAME in order to add brackets around a name.

Another issue in this approach is the optional risk of SQL Injection. QUOTENAME might not be perfect solution but can help in this as well.

If we need to use entities name dynamically like in this case the column name then for most cases using dynamic query is the best solution. This mean to use the Stored Procedure sp_executesql as bellow

```
DECLARE @String INT
SELECT @String = 1
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
SET @SQLString = 
    'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(concat('a',cast(@String as nvarchar))) + ' FROM T'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
GO
```

Comment: See my EDIT. I'm following your advice but still having problems..

Comment: Can you publish DDL+DML + expected result please. You new information brings new issue which is using loop, and not clear to me now what you expect to get as result

Comment: In addition I noticed that you use cast to navarchar which will not fit for the months 10,11,12 instead you should use nvarchar(2)

Comment: And you have a huge iusse now using this part "QUOTENAME ('M',cast(@P_MONTH as nvarchar(2) ))" . You forgot the CONCAT part :-)

Comment: PRINT your query instead of EXECUTE is in order to check the test first. Only after your text is well formatted you can try execute it. You code includes multiple mistakes. I need to go, but if you will add DDL+DML+requested result, then it should be simple to provide working solution for your specific case

Comment: QUOTENAME actually doesn't work. Query executes but in table I got NULL in place where table column values suppose to be.

Comment: please provide the DDL+DML+expected result. Read all my comments fully. Your  new information includes many mistakes in the code which led to this NULL. For example you use QUOTENAME with two parameters input but QUOTENAME have only one parameter input. You messed up the code, but we will fix it. You can see in my sample that QUOTENAME  works well.... just provide the missing information  and we will continue